# Rails ActionMailer parameter is a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use ActionMailer to send an Email.

This is the invoice_mailer.rb

```
class InvoiceMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "ndeavor@ameipro.com"
  def invoice_email(invoice)
    @invoice = invoice
    mail(:to => @invoice.workorder.contact.email, :subject => "nDeavor New Invoice")
  end
end
```

This is the controller code:

```
  def sendinvoice
    @invoice = params[:invoice_id]
    InvoiceMailer.invoice_email(@invoice).deliver
  end
```

This is the view code:

```
<%= link_to 'Send Invoice', invoices_sendinvoice_path(:invoice_id => @invoice), :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

The error I'm getting is from this line in the invoice_mailer:

```
mail(:to => @invoice.workorder.contact.email, :subject => "nDeavor New Invoice")
```

This is the error:

```
undefined method `workorder' for "10":String
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `sendinvoice` method, you have `@invoice = params[:invoice_id]`, which assign 10 to `@invoice` and then you pass it into `InvoiceMailer.invoice_email`.

What you probably want is `@invoice = Invoice.find(params[:invoice_id])`. This will fetch you the Invoice object with id 10.